# open cv cannot find the image

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

The code:

```
 String imageName( "test.jpg" );
 Mat image = imread( imageName,IMREAD_COLOR );
 if( image.empty() )                   
 {
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ; 
    return -1;
 }
 namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 imshow( "Display window", image );
```

The test.jpg file is in the same folder as the cpp file. (cpp file is in "documents/Xcode projects/ocr/ocr/")

But the program displays "Could not open or find the image" and quits. Is there something wrong with the directory of test.jpg or is it something else?

Comment: My guess is that your binary is **not** in the same folder as the cpp file, you can either use an absolute path i.e `/documents/Xcode projects/ocr/ocr/test.jpg` or a relative path from the folder containing the binary i.e `../../ocr/test.jpg`

Comment: @Cyclonecode neither worked. I get the same error. There is no other error in my code. the header and library search paths to open cv were provided and I added the .dylib files too.

Comment: can you try Mat a = Mat(512,512, CV_8UC3); imwrite("testA.jpg", a); and find out whether /where testA.jpg is written to?

Comment: @Cyclonecode is right. Your executable and image file are in two different folders. This exact thing happens to all new programmers. Header and library search paths have nothing to do with loading images. Those are only for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems right there can be 2 problems
1. the name of the image is same as that in location(case sensitive)
2.Use the following code (i have checked it works)

```
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
     Mat img = imread("yourImageNAme", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

     if (img.empty()) 
     {
          cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;

          return -1;
     }

     namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
     imshow("MyWindow", img); 

     waitKey(0);

     destroyWindow("MyWindow"); 

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: it says "error: image cannot be loaded..!!"

Comment: did you try it with other image extensions?

Comment: yes. still does not work